# How to store punch of equations / constants to solve for any element equation or numerical value

Tags: algorithm, wolfram-mathematica

Lets say, that problems are fairly simple - something, that pre-degree theoretical physics student would solve. And student does the hardest part of the task - functional reading: parsing linguistically free form text, to get input and output variables and input variable values.

For example: a problem about kinematic equations, where there are variables `{a,d,t,va,vf}` and few functions that describe, how thy are dependent of each-other. So using skills acquired in playing fitting blocks where thy fit, you play with the equations to get the output variable you where looking for.

In any case, there are exactly 2 possible outputs you might want and thy are (with working example):

1) Equation for that variable

```
Physics[have_, find_] := Solve[Flatten[{
    d == vf * t - (a * t^2) /2, (* etc. *)
    have }], find]
Physics[True, {d}]
{{d -> (1/2)*(2*t*vf - a*t^2)}}
```

2)  Exact or general numerical value for that variable

```
Physics[have_, find_] := Solve[Flatten[{
    d == vf * t - (a * t^2) /2, (* etc. *)
    have }], find]
Physics[{t == 9.7, vf == -104.98, a == -9.8}, {d}]
{{d->-557.265}}
```

I am not sure, that I am approaching the problem correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that I would probably prefer an approach like

```
In[1]:= Physics[find_, have_:{}] := Solve[
  {d == vf*t - (a*t^2)/2 (* , etc *)} /. have, find]

In[2]:= Physics[d]
Out[2]= {{d -> 1/2 (-a t^2 + 2 t vf)}}

In[2]:= Physics[d, {t -> 9.7, vf -> -104.98, a -> -9.8}]
Out[2]= {{d -> -557.265}}
```

Where the `have` variables are given as a list of replacement rules.

As an aside, in these types of physics problems, a nice thing to do is define your physical constants like

```
N[g] = -9.8;
```

which produces a `NValues` for `g`.  Then

```
N[tf] = 9.7;N[vf] = -104.98;
Physics[d, {t -> tf, vf -> vf, a -> g}]
%//N
```

produces

```
{{d->1/2 (-g tf^2+2 tf vf)}}
{{d->-557.265}}
```

Comment: +1 I think this is the best way to go. It's very flexible and let you visualize a lot of properties.

Comment: added an answer with the advantages of your approach. Feel free to  get my image in your answer and I'll delete mine, if you wish.

Comment: @belisarius: I'm happy to leave your answer there -- it saves me editing mine! (+1 for the pretty pictures)

Answer (score 2):

Let me show some advanges of Simon's approach:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are at least approaching this problem reasonably. I see a fine general purpose function and I see you're getting results, which is what matters primarily. There is no 'correct' solution, since there might be a large range of acceptable solutions. In some scenario's some solutions may be preferred over others, for instance because of performance, while that might be the other way around in other scenarios.

The only slight problem I have with your example is the dubious parametername 'have'.
Why do you think this would be a wrong approach?